# How to merge a branch locally and make the log graphs to look like when merged via PR in GitHub

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge, git-log

### This is the flow using GitHub

- I am in `master` in my machine
- I create a branch `some-work`, and I work on it, I make a couple of commits
- I push the `some-work` branch to GitHub, the branch is created in GitHub
- In GitHub: I make a PR, merge `some-work` into `master`, delete `some-work`
- Again in my machine: from `master` I run `git pull origin master`, I delete my local `some-work`

Now, if I run in my mahcine `git log --graph --pretty=format:'%h -%d %s (%cr) <%an>'`. I get something like this:

```
*   83b98e0 - Merge pull request #17 from MyCompany/some-work (11 days ago) 
|\  
| * 8ee6573 - (origin/some-work) A message (11 days ago) 
| * 8ee6573 - (origin/some-work) Another message (11 days ago) 
|/  
*   ...
```

### This is the flow not using GitHub, only my local repository

- I am in `master` in my machine
- I create a branch `some-work`, and I work on it, I make a couple of commits
- I checkout `master`
- I merge `some-work` into `master` (`git merge some-work`)
- [Optional] `git branch -d some-work` and `git push origin master`

Now, if I run in my mahcine `git log --graph --pretty=format:'%h -%d %s (%cr) <%an>'`. I get something like this:

```
  
* 8ee6573 - (HEAD, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) A message (11 days ago) 
* 8ee6573 - Another message (11 days ago) 
*   ...
```

### The question

Is there a way of having the nice graph of the first flow (in which you can clearly see that those two commits have been part of a branch called `some-work`) if I am working like in the second flow? i.e. without using a remote repo to make the merge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is a [fast-forward merge](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging), which is automatically used if the branches did not actually diverge. To avoid the fast-forward and use an explicit merge, try

```
git merge --no-ff some-work
```